# PHP error don't display on Opensuse 11 Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, syntax-error, opensuse

On opensuse 11, Firefox isn't displaying php errors.  For exemple, I have correct.php and broken.php :

```
correct.php
<?php echo("test"); ?>

broken.php
<?php echo("toto ?>
```

Loading correct.php, displaying "test"
Loading broken.php, displaying "test" again

In fact, the loaded page seems the same.

I tried on Windows 7 Firefox and it's showing :

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error...
```

My PC is on Opensuse, I borrowed the Windows one to test this thing...
And I don't have access to the server (only a ftp on a sub-folder of the website)

Thanks a lot if you help me, if you don't thanks anyway cause stackoverflow's helping me a lot (even without asking 8D )

*edit* : If I'm going to broken.php with a link (), the URL isn't changing on OpenSuse FF, on Windows FF it's going to the page with the php error

Answer (score 1):

at the php.ini check if the display_error = on 
if not change it to on then restart the web server 
then try again

Comment: I don't have access to the server... only to a subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: That's usually too late to catch parse errors. He will need to adapt this very setting in the php.ini

Comment: As a workaround try to put `php_value error_reporting 2047` in a `.htaccess` file where your script lives.

Comment: The htaccess file didn't changed a thing neither the cache, is it possible that's a browser config problem ? like a parameter in about:config ?

Comment: Error reporting is printed server side, so no browser setting can suppress error reporting.

Comment: Trying looking in you web hosting provider's control panel (assuming they provide one) alternatively contact them for support.